# Specified child already has parent

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment

I'm currently passing data between two dialogfragments. Whenever the dialog fragment 2 had been done. It will pass the data from to dialog fragment 1. Here the method for dialog fragment 1, it implements an interface that created in dialog fragment 2.

**Dialog Fragment 1**

```
@Override
public void updateContributor(ArrayList<View> imageView) {
    System.out.println("Contributors received from contributer's fragment: " + imageView);
    for ( View child : imageView)
    {
        if (child instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView childImageView = (ImageView) child;
            ll_contributor_list.addView(childImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Dialog Fragment 2**

```
MusicRecorderFragment fragment = (MusicRecorderFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("record_fragment");


            ArrayList<View> views = getAllChildren(ll);

            /*setArguments(args);*/
            fragment.updateContributor(views);
            getDialog().dismiss();
```

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because of your views are already added in some layout and you are trying to add it again to the contributor list which I guess it's a layout. (`ll_contributor_list.addView(childImageView);`)

Try to just collect the data and recreate your view on the other fragment instead of trying to add an already added view to another layout.

Comment: Is there another way to add an item to layout that already added view ?

Comment: If you created the views using xml then the answer is no. If you add them dynamically then you can use the removeView and addView methods.